# LEFT JOIN takes long even with indexes

Tags: mysql

I have two tables both InnoDB.  Both have the column `email` which are indexed.

First tables `users` is 100,000 records.  Second table `preview_movie` is 1,500 records.

I want to get all emails that aren't in the `users` table but exist in the `preview_movie` table.

```
SELECT a.email as email FROM `preview_movie` a  
LEFT JOIN users c on c.email=a.email 
WHERE c.email is NULL
```

I've tried this variation and still takes long:

```
SELECT * FROM `preview_movie` a  
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(SELECT email FROM users B WHERE B.email = a.email)
```

This simple query is taking 70+ seconds to execute.  How do i solve?

Comment: Have you tried using MySQL's EXPLAIN statement? Likely a lot of row scanning. I don't immediately see a raw the first one wouldn't work fast.

Comment: did you see the query plan by
    explain select ....
if you have, show the explain result, too

Comment: you also check the charset and collation of each column, if they are not match, they can't using the index

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on email in both `preview_movie` and `users` tables, and first query should work fast, as long as number of users with NULL email is low.